# GCC can't find stdio.h in Alpine Linux

Tags: gcc, alpine-linux

In a fresh Alpine Linux I installed GCC by

```
apk add --update-cache gcc
```

but still a simple program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    return 0;
}
```

compiled with message

```
fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Install `musl-dev` (in addition to the gcc compiler)

```
apk add musl-dev
```

You need to install it separately because in Alpine Linux, the package GCC doesn't depend on `libc-dev` [for good reason](https://gitlab.alpinelinux.org/alpine/aports/-/issues/3467):

> You can use gcc to compile things without libc, for example hypervisors firmware etc.

And August Klein also noted that in Debian, GCC only *recommends* `libc-dev` for the same reason (but most people don't do `--no-install-recommends` anyway).

Comment: `apk add libc-dev`

Comment: Or, `apk add musl-dev`: `libc-dev` is a meta package that will pull `musl-dev`, which contains the actual files (https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?file=&path=&name=musl-dev&branch=v3.8&repo=main&arch=x86_64)

Comment: Similarly, for me `stdlib.h` was missing and this fixed it.

Comment: Thanks. It also resolves issue with ```sys/socket.h```.