# How to Wrap an Executable in Docker?

Tags: docker

I have an executable binary called `abin` that I want to containerize. All `abin` does is output a test string via `printf`. So I create a directory called `test`, which contains only `abin` and the following `Dockerfile`:

```
from alpine:3.7
copy abin /
entrypoint /abin
```

So I `sudo docker build -t test/testy:tag . && sudo docker run --rm test/testy:tag`, and get the following:

```
/bin/sh: /abin: not found
```

This baffles me for two reasons:

1. why is `sh` running despite setting the entrypoint to `/abin`?
2. why is `/abin` not found?

Changing the entrypoint to `stat /abin` then re-building and re-running gives the expected `stat` output, clearly indicating that there's an executable file at `/abin`. By the same token, removing the entrypoint and running in the container's interactive shell, I can see the `abin` file, and I can `ls` or `stat` and `cat` etc., but `./abin` or `/abin` still give the `/bin/sh: ./abin: not found` error.

EDIT:

I incorrectly assumed that Alpine ran the same kind of binaries as most linuxes. [Not so](https://alpinelinux.org/about/). Also, [it doesn't even come with stdio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42366739/gcc-cant-find-stdio-h-in-alpine-linux) - my second mistake. Lastly, I needed to specify the entrypoint as an absolute path. Thus the following Dockerfile works:

```
from alpine:3.7
workdir /
copy test.c .
run apk add gcc libc-dev && gcc test.c -o abin
entrypoint ["/abin"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your entrypoint is not inside square brackets, Docker will call `sh <entrypoint>`. Use `ENTRYPOINT ["abin"]` instead and I believe it should work.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that. Using the bracketed entrypoint, I get a runtime error: standard_init_linux.go:190: exec user process caused "no such file or directory". Unfortunately searches for this online discuss only golang programs or CRLF troubles. Might you know about this, too?

Comment: What happens if you try, instead of ENTRYPOINT, `CMD ["abin"]`?

Comment: it's the same output

Comment: This is an executable that will run under alpine, right?

Comment: ...turns-out: no. Fixed it. Thank you.